# What is the symbol ≙ most commonly used for in a mathematical or math-related context?

Tags: notation

**What is the symbol `≙` most commonly used for in a mathematical or math-related context?**

- LaTeX produces the symbol with `\hateq`.
- The symbol has Unicode codepoint `U+2259`.
- The [respective Unicode code chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf) shows it with the name `ESTIMATES` and the annotation `= corresponds to`. Note that the names and annotations there are often not helpful, incomplete, or even misleading.
- Entering it into the English Wikipedia currently redirects to the article [Correspondence (mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_%28mathematics%29).

Where and how is `≙` used in math or related fields? (By "related" I am thinking of statistics and physics.)

In German secondary-school math and science classes, it is used to denote "corresponds to" (German: "entspricht") when doing calculations using the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_three). For example: `3 apples ≙ €15;  7 apples ≙ €x`.

Comment: Currently, entering it into the English-language Wikipedia (i.e. browsing to [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/≙](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/≙) redirects to the entry [Binary Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *hat* above the equals sign is an **estimator**. Originaly estimators are used on terms. For example:

$$\widehat{\theta}(X)$$

But it has appeared (sometimes) more convenient to use it with an equals sign, especially in statistics. It has transformed a substantive (*θ* is an estimator for . . .) into a verb.

`x ≙ . . .` then reads as `x estimates . . .`

You use it instead of a plain equals sign when you do not have a strict equality between the  left term and the right expression. Statistically speaking, it symbolizes an estimation of an unobservable quantity.

Answer (score 1):

In statistics, it is to define the sample minimum $x_{(1)}$ or sample maximum $x_{(n)}$.

For example,

$$x_{(1)} ≙  min\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$$

$x_{(1)}$ is also called the smallest observation.

Comment: You didn't explain why this usage is different from a plain equals ("$=$") sign.

Comment: I can see there is no too much difference except that it just emphasizes this is a definition.