# History and current usage of this symbol for "corresponds to"?

Tags: notation

Encyclopedia.com lists the following symbol for "corresponds to":

[image]

The source they give is "Oxford University Press", although I am not sure which exact work they used. But they list the symbol, and the stated meaning of "corresponds to" is the one in which I have been using the symbol for decades.

The symbol also appears [in Unicode](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2259), where it is called "estimates". (It is Unicode symbol U+2259.)

It does not, however, appear to exist in Latex.

What are its history and current usage?

Comment: This isn't a math question.  That said, I have never seen this used.

Comment: @ruffle You can use \hat{=}: $\hat{=}$

Comment: @lulu: this question is completely on-topic for the "Notation" tag, which is for questions "on the meaning, history, and usage of mathematical symbols and notation." Unicode say it's a mathematical operator called "estimates". Curiously for "corresponds to" they use another symbol, [U+2258](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2258), ≘. Perhaps you are more familiar with the latter?

Comment: Asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/790019/917479). It has an answer, but not references either.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is curious, here's the link: https://www.encyclopedia.com/environment/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/basic-mathematical-symbols.

Comment: Kindly reopen this question immediately, which must have been closed by mistake because it patently obviously does meet the company's guidelines. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is that a British usage?  I have been doing mathematics for a very long time and have never seen that symbol.  In fact, if I ran into the statement that "A corresponds to B" I would expect a definition of the exact correspondence.

Comment: I learnt it in Britain and have always called it "corresponds to". [Codepoints](https://codepoints.net/U+2259?lang=en) call it "corresponds to" too, although in Unicode its name is "estimates".

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `\widehat =`? It looks like $\widehat=$.